# How to initialize a member array with a lenght given as object parameter

Tags: c++

I don't manage to determine the size of a member array from a parameter passed to the object.

**For now I have something like this, which works even if not very convenient: the size of the member array is defined directly in the class header.**

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Test foo;
}
```

class_test.cpp:

```
Test::Test()
{

}
```

class_test.h:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test();

    private:
        std::array<int,10> myarray; // I define the size here. 
};
```

**Now I would like to pass the array size as a parameter when I create the object. 
Something like this:**

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Test foo(10); // I pass the array size
}
```

class_test.cpp:

```
Test::Test(int size): arraysize(size) // I affect the size to a class attribute
{

}
```

class_test.h:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test(int size);

    private:
        int arraysize;
        std::array<int,arraysize> myarray; // I use the attribute to determine the member array size
};
```

I tried a lot of solutions but in the end I always have compile errors. 
I saw the other threads on this subject but they didn't allowed me to find how to deal with this configuration.

I could use a vector but in my situation the array's extra performance is very beneficial.

Comment: Template parameters have to be known at compile time, not at runtime like you want. Also you cannot inline variable length array into a struct. That would make the size of the struct depending on a parameter which C++ (and AFAIK any other language) does not allow. Have you actually measured that array's performance actually matters? Cause to be honest, this sounds unlikely. What kind of code exactly makes that difference?

Comment: It's a Game of life project and I measured that iterating over a std::array is twice as fast than over a vector, even if the two are already fast. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array's size must be known at compile time (in other words, it's constant).

Either you use `std::vector`, or you bake that size in the type:

```
template<int N> // make it a template parameter
class Test
{
    public:
        Test() {}

    private:
        std::array<int, N> myarray;
};

Test<10> test; // array of 10 elements.
```

Personally, I'd recommend vectors, since I doubt the performance difference is that big.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is for a Game of life project and I measured that iterating over a std::array is twice as fast than over a vector, which can have an impact for very long containers. I will try both solutions though! Thank you.

Comment: Since most vectors implementations essentially use a dynamically allocated array underneath, the performance should be identical, unless you take into account whatever safety mechanism a vector adds in debug mode. I suggest you do your test with optimizations turned on and debug checks turned off, to ensure a proper comparison.

Comment: You are absolutely right! With the -O3 g++ option there is no measurable difference.  Thank you so much for this remark.